# Voseo in Guatemala

Tags: gramática, pronombres, voseo, ustedeo, guatemala

**Spanish version:**

Tengo una pregunta sobre las percepciones sociales del "voseo" y el "tuteo" en Guatemala. Agradecería su ayuda.

1. En Guatemala, en comparación con “vos” y “usted”, ¿qué nivel de informalidad o formalidad tiene el “tú”?
2. ¿En qué momento los amigos masculinos y femeninos dejan de usar “usted” y empiezan a usar “tú”? Entiendo que probablemente no haya una regla “formal,” pero ¿qué creen ustedes?
3. ¿Es cierto que el uso de “tú” entre amigos de diferentes géneros implica interés en una relación romántica? ¿Es éste siempre el caso?

Gracias! :)

---

**English version:**

I have a question about the social perceptions of “voseo” and “tuteo” in Guatemala. I would appreciate your help.

1. In Guatemala, in comparison with “vos” and “usted,” what level of
   informality or formality does “tú” have?
2. At what point do male and female friends move from using “usted” to “tú”? I understand that there is probably not a formal rule, but I'm curious to see what you think.
3. Is it true that friends of different genders using “tú” implies an interest in a romantic relationship? Is this always the case?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

1.- El "voseo" se restringe al ámbito íntimo. El "tuteo" es para la confianza intermedia.

2.- Entre amigos y personas de confianza se mantiene el "voseo". El "ustedeo" se usaba como forma tradicional de respeto, pero esta situación ha ido variando gracias a la influencia de "Costa Rica" y en algunos lugares es posible escucharla en diferentes situaciones y con distintos interlocutores.

3.- En el trato entre hombres y mujeres que recién se conocen, se utiliza el "tu", pero esto no implica ningún tipo de interés en una relación amorosa. El uso del "tu" entre hombres esta mal visto.

---

Guatemala tradicionalmente se había considerado un país de la América tuteante-voseante, por tanto, en principio dependerá de la zona donde la influencia de uno u otro ("voseo"-"tuteo") sea mayor. Sin embargo, aunque últimamente el "voseo" es un fenómeno regional cada vez más desprestigiado hay que hacer notar la relevancia e influencia cada vez mayor que tiene el "ustedeo".

Por "ustedeo" debe entenderse el empleo de "usted" en situaciones de confianza o intimidad, es decir, entre amigos, novios o cónyuges, de padres a hijos, etc. No se emplea este término como marcador de distancia

Tradicionalmente en Guatemala, la influencia mexicana, había estado presente en los medios de comunicación e incluso los medios oficiales prefieren el uso del "tu". Sin embargo, en campañas de publicidad y con la mayoría de las personas de confianza, amigos y entre familia se tratan en el mayor de los casos con el pronombre personal "vos" en lugar de "tú", *dejando este último para el trato entre hombres y mujeres que recién se conocen*.

Ese mismo "recién conocerse" o confianza espontánea y el uso del "tu" entre hombres es mal visto y puede ser motivo de malentendidos.

Sin embargo, el fenómeno del "ustedeo" más propio de lugares como "Costa Rica" ha ido ganando terreno e influencia, y ahora muchos emplean esta formula del "usted", tanto en Guatemala como en otros países como El Salvador, Panamá y parte de Colombia. Su uso, aunque aún no es extremo como en Costa Rica, cada vez es más utilizado en Guatemala, ya sea en situaciones formales e informales o como voz dirigida hacia cualquier interlocutor.